# Create a local MS SQL Database on OSX Yosemite

Tags: software-development, osx, database

I need to do some tests on a MS SQL (not MySQL) database. But without the burden of having to open a hosting account, create a remote database, connect to it, and remotely insert a million records.

I need to create a MS SQL Database locally on my computer only to be used on my computer - and I need to be able to import it using Navicat software.

How can we create a local MS SQL database on OS X [Yosemite]?

Comment: Are you saying Microsoft sql server instance?

Comment: @Saifur pretty much, yeah.

Comment: You can run SQL for Linux on OS X via Docker.
Instructions on this blog post : https://medium.com/@reverentgeek/sql-server-running-on-a-mac-3efafda48861

Comment: @BartCalixto Welcome to Software Recommendations! Thanks for this excellent element of answer. This site has a very strict rule: all answers must satisfy [the answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality). Your answer above did not comply with these guidelines, so I had to remove it. Please don't give up, read the guidelines and post again. It should give the main steps of the procedure, price/license information, and limitations if any. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot install MS SQL server directly on OS X operating system. Only option is Windows servers/OS. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#pmosr)

Then do you have any option? Yes. VMs

1. [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/): Virtualize the window OS and install that in there.
2. [Vmware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion): Virtualizing the OS

My personal preference is VMware Fusion. I used it and pretty simple and better than Parallels, at least for me.

And, unfortunately they are not free

Comment: VirtualBox is both Free and free and runs great on Mac. And Linux.  And Windows.

Answer (score 1):

A free (as a beer) setup could be like this:

- get [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (free)
- if you don't own a Windows license, download [the 90-days trial](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-1-enterprise)
- not sure if it already includes the SQL server, if not, download and install [the Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) (free)

This is a bit involved due to all downloads/installations and (unless you already have Windows) will only run for 90 days. Another option is to get an [Amazon Instance](http://aws.amazon.com/windows) with everything already installed, connect per RDP ([CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) is nice) and do your tests remotely.